# How to export subtables to csv format in Piwik

Tags: csv, export, matomo

Current implementation of Piwik exports all 1st level tables to csv format.I want to export 
subTables also with parent table.Is there any way to do this.Please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue found in Piwik trac: http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/2005

I guess you will have to wait that this is implemented... or submit a patch